# Powershell to Invoke-RestMethod is throwing error

Tags: powershell, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We are using powershell script in Azure DevOps to Invoke RestAPI using below command:

```
$Body = @{
"OperationType" = "new"
"ChangeType" = "ZMCR"
"LongDescription" = "Test Description of Change"
"ShortDescription" = "Test Short Description"
"CycleTypeId" = "8200000083"
"FuncUser" = "123"
"ProductId" = "123"
"ExtrefNumber" = "Ext Ref Number"
"ChangeTypeCd" = "ZMHF"
"StepApproverPartnerid" = "5048"
} | ConvertTo-Json


# Send a POST request including bearer authentication.
$params = @{
 'Method' = 'Post'
 'Uri' = 'https://abcdefgh'
 'APIKey' = '6789034'
 'Accept' = '*/*'
 'Body' = '$Body'
 'ContentType' = 'application/json'
 }
 Invoke-RestMethod @params
```

But on execution of the pipeline, we are getting error:

```
2022-10-14T16:11:19.6120102Z Invoke-RestMethod : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'APIKey'.
2022-10-14T16:11:19.6122357Z At D:\a\_temp\15010f41-4006-46a8-8ae1-a7552a46383a.ps1:30 char:20
2022-10-14T16:11:19.6125176Z +  Invoke-RestMethod @params
2022-10-14T16:11:19.6125924Z +                    ~~~~~~~
2022-10-14T16:11:19.6126849Z     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
2022-10-14T16:11:19.6128067Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Request anyone of you to please help us in this.

Comment: The values in `$params` are just arguments passed to `Invoke-RestMethod` - if you take a look at the docs for `Invoke-RestMethod` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod there is no  parameter called `APIKey`. At a guess you want something like "Example 5: Pass multiple headers" to pass these values?

Comment: Also note that `Body' = '$Body'` won't work as intended -string interpolation only works inside `"..."` strings; in this case, just `Body = $Body` should do.

Comment: Yes, I would like to pass values in params as a part of request. Can I send these values making them as Headers ? Or even for APIKey (in case I include it in header) , it is going to show me the error again?

Comment: @MisterSmith you should post that as an Answer. I'd vote for it.

Comment: @MisterSmith - thank you for your valuable answer. It worked when we added APIKey as a part of header like this:


       $headers = @{
        'ContentType' = 'application/json'
        'Accept' = 'application/json'
        'APIKey' = '12345'
    }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MisterSmith and @mklement0 for your valuable suggestions. I have followed the same and reproduced and fixed the issue.

I am also faced same issue
[image]
Fixed by following workaround

#### Workaround

```
$Body = @{
"test" = "testapi"
}

$headers = @{
    'Accept' = 'application/json'
    'Content-Type' ='application/json'
    'Authorization' = '<Your Authorization>'
}


$params = @{
     'Method' = 'Post'
     'Uri' = '< Api url>'
     # Assigned the header & Body values 
     'Headers'= $headers
     'Body' = $Body
 }
 $test = Invoke-RestMethod @params
```

#### Result

[image]